# unable to connect to the remote server from .com domain

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-services, web

i have create a one web service and tested it in local machine, it working fine. So i have hosted it in .com domain. but when i call that web service, it gives me:

> unable to connect to the remote server.

So i have also hosted it .in domain. it working fine with .in domain.

I have already tried with proxy but still same error.
My code is:

```
//Call Send SMS API
string sendSMSUri = "http://smsindia.itworldindia.com/sendhttp.php";

//Create HTTPWebrequest
HttpWebRequest httpWReq = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(sendSMSUri);
httpWReq.Proxy = new System.Net.WebProxy(sendSMSUri);
//Prepare and Add URL Encoded data
UTF8Encoding encoding = new UTF8Encoding();
byte[] data = encoding.GetBytes(sbPostData.ToString());
//Specify post method
httpWReq.Method = "POST";
httpWReq.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
httpWReq.ContentLength = data.Length;
using (Stream stream = httpWReq.GetRequestStream())
{
    stream.Write(data, 0, data.Length);
}

//Get the response
HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)httpWReq.GetResponse();
StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream());
string responseString = reader.ReadToEnd();
//Close the response
reader.Close();
response.Close();
```

Can anybody help me how to resolve that issue?

Comment: could it be a `CORS` issue?

Comment: what is CORS? it thows "unable to connect to the remote server." error

Comment: `Cross-origin resource sharing`. You might want to tell us what's the HTTP return code, and to check if the server needs credentials to be accessed.

Comment: Is this "smsindia.itworldindia.com" service yours? Also please comment if your "in" an "com" domain machines are the same or if they are different. Maybe you're just blocking traffic in the "com" one, or you have a specified port redirect .